# The word mə·ra·ḥe·p̄eṯ translation in Genesis 1:2

Tags: hebrew, aramaic

According to Biblehub.com, the word מְרַחֶ֖פֶת, that is mə·**ra·ḥe·p̄eṯ** should be translated  "To brood" (One possibility). However, that Bible passage (Genesis 1:2) is almost always translated as "... and the Spirit of God was hovering over the waters." (Genesis 1:2) Mythologist Martti Haavio has claimed that the word **rahāf** **in the Syrian language** (also the Semitic language) which also means **'to brood'** , should be taken into account in this context to support the argument that the word מְרַחֶ֖פֶת would be translated in the same way in this passage. So he says the sentence should be translated: "And the Spirit of God was brooding over the surface of the waters." In support, he presents well-known mythological references to the spirit as a bird. For example, in the creation myth of Phoenician Mythology, there is also an egg (mōt) and, as is well known, in many other Eastern cultures the divine spirit has sometimes been described as a bird (also in the Bible, the Holy Spirit -> Matthew 3:16)

My question is this: Are there grounds for such a translation on linguistic grounds, given the references I gave, about mythology, as Haavio claims in his book?

Comment: This would be a better fit on the Biblical Hermeneutics StackExchange site. Be careful: the English word _brood_ has several different meanings, and it is not clear to me which of them the Aramaic word רחף corresponds to.  To me _was brooding over the surface off the waters_ would not suggest procreation at all, but deep thought.  And the meanings in Hebrew seem closer to that sense. But I don't know about the Aramaic.

Comment: The bird-related meaning would be supported by Deuteronomy 32:11, “Like an eagle that stirs up its nest, that flutters over its young” (ESV), where *flutters* is the rendering of Hebrew *rxp*, translated with Aramaic *rxp* in Targum Neofiti.

Comment: Matthew is writing many centuries later, and the metaphor ‘bird for spirit’ seems pretty easy to make twice independently. At least in Aramaic, the root is primarily if not solely related to the Holy Spirit and consecration, not birds. In the Hebrew Bible the last reference is Jeremiah 23:9, best translated *shake*.

Answer (score 2):

Welcome to the site!  You might get a fuller picture from the Biblical Hermeneutics StackExchange site, which could discuss translations into other other languages and the history of the tradition.  I will limit my answer to the linguistic aspects.

> Mythologist Martti Haavio has claimed that the word rahāf in the
> Syrian language (also the Semitic language) which also means 'to
> brood' , should be taken into account in this context to support the
> argument that the word מְרַחֶ֖פֶת would be translated in the same way
> in this passage. So he says the sentence should be translated: "And
> the Spirit of God was brooding over the surface of the waters."

[This online Aramaic dictionary](https://cal.huc.edu/) includes this entry:

> rwḥpw, rwḥpwtˀ   (ruḥḥāp̄ū, ruḥḥāp̄ūṯā)   n.f.  incubation

(Note that "p" and "f" can represent the same phoneme in Aramaic.)

[This dictionary](https://cal.huc.edu/showjps.php?jpspage=538) includes as an entry for the pael form of *raḥāf* the translation "to brood, hover over; to take care of with ܥܠ" and gives two Aramaic examples with these English translations:

> "a hen brooding over her young" and "[the Spirit of God] brooding over
> the face of the waters"

From these and other dictionaries, it does appear that one of the meanings of the Pael form of *raḥāf* was "to brood."

The next question is what significance this has for the Hebrew word מְרַחֶ֖פֶת (məraḥeffet), which has two parts: (1) What would the Aramaic word mean in this context and (2) What should this tell us about possible meanings of the Hebrew.

I looked at *The Complete Aramaic English Interlinear Peshitta Old Testament* available on [this site](https://pdfcoffee.com/qdownload/the-complete-aramaic-english-interlinear-peshitta-old-testament-pdf-free.html) and found the word מרחפא in Genesis translated as "hover," which contradicts the translation I found in the dictionary sited above.

When you look through the various entries in the dictionaries for *raḥāf* and its derivatives (e.g, https://cal.huc.edu/ under ܪܚܦ), you actually find a variety of meanings, including:

1. to brood, hover  PTA, Syr. TN Deut32:11 : כנשרה דמעורר קנה על גוזלוי מרחף‏  [=MT כְּנֶשֶׁר יָעִיר קִנּוֹ עַל־גּוֹזָלָיו יְרַחֵף] †. JSB4 279:4 : ܪܚܦܬ ܬܡܢ ܒܝܬ ܐܪܡܠܬܐ‏  (the Holy Spirit) hovered over the widow’s house. P Gn1:2 : ܘܪܘܚܗ ܕܐܠܗܐ ܡܪܚܦܐ ܥܠ ܐ̈ܦܝ ܡ̈ܝܐ‏ . (a) to cover, protect  Syr. AphDem10.192:21 : ܐܒܐ ܡܪܚܡܢܐ܂ ܕܪܚܦ ܥܠ ܒܢܘ̈ܗܝ‏ .
2. to incline something over something  Syr. ZDMG 27:574:v347 .
3. to hover over  (b) fig. : to threaten  Syr. IA2 32:v172 : ܡܐ ܕܡܬܪܚܦ ܩܢܛܐ ܒܟܘܠܐ‏  when fear hovers over everything.
4. to carry out consecration  Syr. TDN.132:3 : ܡܫܡ̈ܫܢܐ ܢܪܚܦܘܢ‏  the ministers should perform the consecration.

In theory, any of these meanings could apply to the passage in Genesis; however, it seems to me that some are more primary and more likely than others.

In Hebrew, we have two citations of derivatives of the root רחפ (rḥf), besides the one in Genesis: the one in Deuteronomy 32:11, probably referring to an eagle hovering over its young (עַל־גֹּוזָלָ֖יו יְרַחֵ֑ף) and the one in Jeremiah 23:9, probably referring to the unsteadiness or quivering of one's bones (רָֽחֲפוּ֙ כָּל־עַצְמֹותַ֔י).

The root meaning that might explain all these derivations might have something to do with unsteadiness.  In Aramaic, the development might be that using the Pael would add an idea of repetitive motion so that unsteady > quiver > flutter > hover (over) > protect > brood, in one development, and unsteady > quiver > flutter > waver > wave (hand over) > consecrate, in another development.  In Hebrew, we only have firm evidence of unsteady > quiver > flutter > hover.

The Aramaic meaning of "brood" seems to be quite specific; whereas the meaning "hover" seems to apply to a wider array of things (e.g., an eagle and fear), including to God's spirit/wind.  "Hovering" also seems to be the primary meaning for something thought of as moving or active, which begs the question of whether we are talking about something like a "still spirit/still wind brooding" or a "blowing wind/active spirit hovering" when talking of God's attributes.  The former may give an idea of hatching creation like an egg, and the latter gives the idea of wind or spirit rippling over the waters and stirring them into life.  It is also possible that the ideas are not opposed and that the word creates the image of the spirit/wind of God "tending to the waters" in both senses.

On balance, I think the idea of "brooding" cannot be excluded; however, there is not clear evidence of it in Hebrew and even in Aramaic that meaning is not necessarily prominent.  Another reason not to apply that meaning is that in the verse in Genesis, it is not clear that anything is hatched from the waters or that they are in the same position as young to be brooded over; instead, the waters appear to be only a backdrop for other activity, which would favor a meaning emphasizing movement or activity, like "hovering," focusing on the action of the spirit or wind of God.

Aramaic is closely related to Hebrew, but had many of its own grammatical and lexical developments.  It also has an incredibly long history over a wide area, so that what one can say about one stage of the language in one area does not always apply to another stage in another area.

It is very appropriate to use Aramaic to fill gaps in our knowledge of Hebrew, but less appropriate to use it to expand on already established meanings.  It is unclear when all the subsidiary meanings developed in Aramaic, so that it is possible that the meaning of "brood" was not available when Genesis was written, just as the meaning of "consecrate" seems to be a late development.